# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EntityManager" , when trying to start jboss v5.0.4, jboss.javaee.jar is well placed in the lib folder

Tags: java, jboss, entitymanager

```html
  the stack error:

15:59:09,062 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/D:/projectfoldername/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/.ear file / state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying model.jar: LEntityManager;
 at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:196)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:99)
 at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractVFSRealDeployer.java:45)
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
 at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
 at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
 at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LEntityManager;
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
 at org.jboss.aop.Advisor.doDeployAnnotationOverride(Advisor.java:455)
 at org.jboss.aop.Advisor$DeployAnnotationOverrideAction$2.deploy(Advisor.java:2021)
 at org.jboss.aop.Advisor.deployAnnotationOverride(Advisor.java:416)
 at org.jboss.aop.Advisor.deployAnnotationOverrides(Advisor.java:400)
 at org.jboss.aop.ClassAdvisor.rebindClassMetaData(ClassAdvisor.java:1225)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ManagedObjectAdvisor.rebindClassMetaData(ManagedObjectAdvisor.java:180)
 at org.jboss.aop.ClassAdvisor$1.run(ClassAdvisor.java:292)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.jboss.aop.ClassAdvisor.attachClass(ClassAdvisor.java:276)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ManagedObjectAdvisor.initialize(ManagedObjectAdvisor.java:174)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.initialize(ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.java:70)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.AbstractContainer.initializeAdvisor(AbstractContainer.java:162)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.BeanContainer.initialize(BeanContainer.java:206)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.<init>(EJBContainer.java:249)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.<init>(SessionContainer.java:119)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.<init>(SessionSpecContainer.java:69)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.<init>(StatelessContainer.java:112)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getStatelessContainer(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:310)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getContainers(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:203)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:718)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:669)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployUrl(Ejb3Deployment.java:651)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deploy(Ejb3Deployment.java:614)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:491)
 at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:182)
 ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EntityManager
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:292)
 at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
 at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
 at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
 ... 62 more
15:59:09,234 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/D:/projectfoldername/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/.ear file/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EntityManager

15:59:09,312 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
15:59:09,375 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
15:59:09,375 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 2m:24s:391ms
```

please help, as I have placed the javaee.jar in the lib folder, also the jar is present in the buildpath of the project . why this error is giving , i am not able to configure. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the *javaee.jar* to the jboss classpath ?

Comment: can you please guide me the step to do that?

Comment: There is a *Lib* folder in the *jboss-as\server\[default]\lib* (I'm assuming you are deploying to default). You can place the jar in that folder, or in the deploy folder.

Comment: D:\projectfolder\jboss\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib\classes12.jar

Comment: shall i need to add anything more in the lib of jboss??

Comment: When I rebuild the project the error has gone.. Server ran well, without error. but when trying to run localhost in the browser , showing 404,

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /a

type Status report

message /a

description The requested resource (/a) is not available.....

Comment: but the insteat another project's localhost is running on localhost:8080/b in the browser...